# soapUI reuse common test by 'Run Testcase' will let the steps dead

Tags: soapui

I have created a common test case, then other many cases will reuse this case. See screen shot.
But after I created "Run TestCase", then common test case steps will dead.
Any idea?

Run Testcase setting

*Before run test case*
[image: []

*After run , common steps is dead , can't open and REST iocn is gone*
[image: []

Comment: I am using Ready API 1.5.0

Comment: You may try maintenance build to see if that issue is gone, check here - https://support.smartbear.com/downloads/readyapi/nightly-builds/  Otherwise, if the issue is stil persists, raise a case with support https://support.smartbear.com/product-list/

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Can you provide [mcve]?